# Android External GPS device receiver

Tags: android, gps, external

I want to create an Android application which uses an external device's GPS coordinates (because the mobile devices have a less accurate GPS).

The device I am trying to run with is [Trimble GPS Receiver Pro 6T](http://www.trimble.com/mappinggis/pro6.aspx)

Any suggestions how I can get the data from this GPS device and get this data to the mobile device? I've tried searching for some libraries and guides but found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way for your case is to use the NMEA format.
Each GPS reciever can be set to output in NMEA format via serial COM.
You parse the socket, line by line.
Searching for Nmea Parser will give you some src code.